# generate emails from node.js app on debian server

Tags: node.js, debian, email

I'm using node.js on my debian box at home. I want to build a function in my web app that will send an email -- what's the easiest way to setup my home debian server to send emails?

The production webhost will already have email configured, I just need it working locally for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done this in a while, but https://github.com/niftylettuce/node-email-templates is worth checking out. You can also browse npm for the keyword 'email': https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/email. I see at least one sendmail wrapper, that's about as simple as you can get on a Linux box.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at doing this...looks like you can use an smtp server, so I don't need local email on server.

Comment: node-email-templates was the solution for me: npm install email-templates.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer). It supports configuration of various transports that makes it easy to switch between a development enviroment and a production server.